# How to vlookup on 2 columns and return total value of another?

Tags: excel, vlookup

I've got a table in Excel which is structure like so:

```
Month    Date        Time    ID         Name    Currency    Value
Jan      07/01/14    5       1234567    Ted     GBP         500
Jan      10/01/14    12      1234567    Ted     GBP         723
Feb      23/02/14    6       9877654    John    GBP         300
Feb      10/02/14    10      1234567    Ted     GBP         333
```

What I need to do is write a formula which basically returns be the total of Value where ID and Month are equal to whatever the lookup values are. For example, using the above I would say:

> Find the total of Value where Month equals Jan and ID equals 1234567.

The answer in this case would be 1223.

Ive just tried

```
=SUMIFS(INPUT!H:H,INPUT!D:D='TRANS BY MID'!B2,INPUT!A:A='TRANS BY MID'!C1)
```

**INPUT!H:H** is my ID column

**INPUT!D:D='TRANS BY MID'!B2** is the ID I want to use

**INPUT!A:A** is the Month column

**TRANS BY MID'!C1** is Jan

Comment: look into [SUMIFs](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumifs-function-HA010047504.aspx)

Comment: Could also make a fairly simple macro to do the job. But otherwise as @simoco mentioned you can use SUMIF

Comment: Just looked into SUMIFS but seem to be getting an error.  Updating post

Comment: You don't have correct syntax - replace two internal = signs with commas like this =SUMIFS(INPUT!H:H,INPUT!D:D,'TRANS BY MID'!B2,INPUT!A:A,'TRANS BY MID'!C1)

Answer (score 0):

To provide a working solution I simplified your question into one sheet.  The data appears like this:

[image]

You can link your other sheet to the values shown in column `J`.

The formula is now this:

```
=SUMIFS(G:G,D:D,J1,A:A,J2)
```

The result is shown in `J7`:

[image]